# Apache HttpComponents URIBuilder rest with multivalue params

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to send a GET request to an endpoint similar to this:

```
  http://{hostname}api/search/artifact?name=junit&repos=snapshot,deploy,release
```

I have a parameter (repos) with comma separated values. I am looking a way to send this request with URIBuilder of Apache HttpComponents. I have tried constructing NameValuePair ( same name[repos] but different values), but this is format is not valid for the api.  Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not combine the multiple value yourself into a single value "snapshot,deploy,release".

```
String.join(",", reposList);
```